# Having Trouble with ODBC DSNs and 32 bit vs 64 bit

Tags: vb.net, 32bit-64bit, openedge, dsn, progress-db

I am writing an application to interface with a Progress DataBase in VB.net. My development machine is a 32bit Win 7 computer. I have a System DSN configured for the database that I need to use. Since it's on a 32 bit machine its a 32 bit DSN.

App works great on my local computer, the problem arises when I try to take it to one of our 64 bit machines. Now the 64 bit machines seem to have the 32 bit driver installed on them (I opened `C:\Windows\SysWow64\odbcad32.exe` which, based on research, should show my all 32 bit System DSNs and all User DSNs) and a seemingly same DSN (named the same way and everything) exists in System DSNs.

I tried compiling for `x86` instead of `AllCPUs`, but I still get errors. Some of the errors are below.

Any suggestions on how to fix this so that it runs on both 64 and 32 bit machines? Is there a way to make double sure that the 64 bit machines are working on the 32 bit DSNs?

My understanding of Error [IM014] is that the program is finding the DSN on the 64 bit machine, but cant use it, because it's a 32 bit DSN.

Most of the errors for the second error are on [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937531%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) All the 08S01's are "Communication Link Failures", the IM006 is "Driver's SQLSetConnectOption failed" and apparently HY000 has about 20 different meanings.

```
DSN Connection String, Target CPU: AllCPUs, 32 Bit Machine : Runs Fine
DSN Connection String, Target CPU: AllCPUs, 64 Bit Machine : Error [IM014]
DSN Connection String, Target CPU: x86    , 32 Bit Machine : Runs Fine
DSN Connection String, Target CPU: x86    , 64 Bit Machine : Error [HY000]
                                                                   [HYC00]
                                                                   [08S01]
                                                                   [08S01]
                                                                   [08S01]
                                                                   [IM006]
'Yes all of those errors on the last one are from one connection attempt.
```

Comment: Have you looked up those error codes?  The fact that you get different codes on the 64-bit system depending on whether the app is 32-bit or 64-bit suggests that the actual issue may be different.

Comment: Yes I've looked up the errors. and what might it suggest then? My connection string couldn't be much simpler. `DSN=blackring;uid=demo;pwd=demo` all the ports and other things are set in the DSNs and when I click Test connection they work fine.

Comment: It's also about DSNs and usage of DSNs in connection strings. If you consider all the database vendors a third party product, then oracle, Mssql, mysql, PostGres and all the rest would be off topic as well.

Comment: If it helps, even accessing direct through drivers instead of DSNs works on the 32 bit dev machine but not on the 64 bit machines

Comment: @HansPassant after some looking again I found a progress tag. and I'm guessing that your comment with the exact text of the close vote is the one that is pertinent

Comment: This may be a longshot but have you downloaded the latest 64 bit drivers for your database? Are you attempting to use the 32 bit drivers on a 64 bit machine?

Comment: Have you checked the Progress Knowledgebase? There seems to be some matching entries. For example this one: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P169801?q=IM014&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1

Comment: @Jensd I've checked into that. The DSN on the 64 bit machines is a 32 bit DSN. 32 bit DSN 32 bit executable. I dont know about the drivers (installed years ago before I was here) but the 32 bit DSN test connection in the ODBC data source manager (32 bit version in Syswow64) thing tests the connection as fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these links:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/getting-data-between-excel-and-sql-server-using-odbc--/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/abf34eea-1029-429a-b88e-4671bffcee76/why-cant-32-and-64-bit-access-database-engine-aceoledb-dataproviders-coexist

Microsoft allows either 32 or 64 bit drivers.  If you have office32 then you have the 32 bit driver.  The second link shows a work around of sorts.

Regards

Ignacio

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by compiling my vb.net code in Target CPU = x64 in the Commpile option of Visual Studio 2019.Works perfect now.